# Detect camera used (front-facing or rear-facing camera)

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, image-capture

I want to detect which camera that my user used to capture an image, to then initialize a value according to the type (Front/Rear camera).

The following is my trying, After I run the app, value is always 0.417 !

```
public class Home extends Activity {
double value = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.MainActivity);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    input = new EditText(this);
    builder.setView(input);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Next", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int witch) {
            Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File file = getFile();
            camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
            startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAM_REQUEST);
        }
    });

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAM_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Enrollment.class);
            Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                this.value = 0.417;
            }
            else if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK){
                this.value = 0.5;
            }
            startActivity(intent);                
    }
}
```

BTW, capture image work perfectly, I just need to determine the type of camera (front or rear).

Answer (score 2):

You have no way of knowing whether the image came from a front-facing camera, a rear-facing camera, or anything else (an IP camera, a fake picture, etc.). You are delegating the image capture to a third-party app. What that third party app does is up to that app's developers and the user.

Comment: So is it impossible to know which camera?! I need to know if is there is a way even if it will takes a lot of time

Comment: @SheikhahMaasher: "So is it impossible to know which camera?" -- correct. "I need to know if is there is a way even if it will takes a lot of time " -- write your own camera app, using the camera hardware APIs (e.g., `android.hardware.Camera`. Then, *you* are in control of taking the picture, and *you* are responsible for identifying the available cameras and letting the user choose which camera to use.

Comment: I agree with **CommonsWare** on this. Furthermore, you should not be afraid of "write your own camera app", or an Activity to take a picture. This is not too hard with the standard Camera API, and will deliver images as good as the stock camera app on your device.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say this is a guaranteed solution, but it should at least get you something. Each image file will have an `ExifInterface` which lists various details about the image. You can compare a field (focal length e.g.) on the image with the physical hardware values using the camera libraries.