# How to check which of the cameras took the photo?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, camera, android-camera-intent

I'm making an Android application, that uses the device's camera to take a photo.

After the photo is taken, I want to know if it was taken using the front or the back camera.

Any ideas?

Comment: check this so answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875136/detect-camera-used-front-facing-or-rear-facing-camera

Comment: @DaminiMehra thanks :)